# Set Sender in sending Email

Tags: python, email, smtplib

how can I set the sender in email in both yahoo and gmail.

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "New Updates"
msg['From'] = "Unirises Updates!"
msg['To'] = client_mail

html_updates = """<h1>This is automated Email, Test purpose only!</h1>"""
letter = MIMEText(html_letter, "html")
msg.attach(letter)


# Then the rest of code is continue here
```

But in the inbox

[image: mail]

I want to inform the user that the email is came from my email 
example (no-reply@unirises.test)

Comment: You literally have `msg['From']` in your code...

Comment: But I want to ask how can I input no-reply@unirises.test in email but nut in content of mail,

Answer (score 0):

You only provided how you compose the message, while `SMTP.sendmail` which you probably uses later, takes `from_addr` email as first argument - check [sendmail documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html#smtplib.SMTP.sendmail).

Usually the email sending looks like this:

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP(host, port)
smtp.sendmail(from_address_here, to_address_here, msg.as_string())
```

While what you set as `msg["From"]` is more of a display name.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/email-examples.html you can do something like this:

```
msg['From'] = 'Foo Bar <foo.bar@gmail.com>'
```